Partner Center API > Granting auto consent for customer tenant returns 403
For at least 1 year we were using /v1/customers/{{CUSTOMER_TENANT_ID}}/applicationconsents endpoint to auto-grant consent for partner app to the customer tenant. However starting from today the endpoint returns 403 without any further clarification.
Did anything change on the endpoint itself? Is there a workaround?
Note: There is a valid active GDAP relationship between partner and customer, with Global Administrator role assigned.

We are seeing the same.  No code changes on our side, but now all attempts to add or remove app consents result in a 403 response with an empty response body

The issue was resolved yesterday. We have created support ticket through Partner Center portal, and confirmed that it was an issue with latest build, and later it was resolved.

The Partner Center Service Health dashboard has a relevant notice on it:

Last updated:December 10, 2024 at 5:33:04 PM


Some Partner users are unable to access customers M365 Admin Center
Portal via GDAP (Admin on Behalf Of). Partners will receive a generic
permissions error. M365 Admin Center Engineering teams are working on
the resolving the issue.

While not an exact description of the issue I believe this is the cause.
https://partner.microsoft.com/dashboard/v2/support/service-health-status

Thank you, this is probably the issue. We are facing the same problem in our CSP, didn't think to look here.

Same issue here, thank you for this information.
